# Represent polymorphic association in Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database

Symfony 6.2. I want to represent the following in Doctrine: I have a Cat entity and a Dog entity, and an Event entity. A Cat can have many Events, so can a Dog. An Event can have just one Cat or just one Dog.

So it's kind of a polymorphic relationship. I don't want to add a target_type and target_id field to the Event table, because I want to preserve foreign IDs. So I have decided to have 2 separate tables: cat_event and dog_event.

```
| cat_event | dog_event |
| --------  | --------- |
| cat_id    | dog_id    |
| event_id  | event_id  |
```

The problem is, I am not sure how to represent this in the Doctrine attribute syntax. What I have tried: creating a many-to-many relation between cat and event (I know it's not many-to-many, but this at least creates the join table). But this then makes the event think it has many cats, whereas it can only have one cat. It's also important that an event be aware of whether it has a cat or a dog.

Comment: Have you read the doctrine documentation for "Inheritance mapping"? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance . I think it can be useful. Maybe you can try to create a base "Animal" abstract entity with dog and cat extending it, then refer to that animal abstract entity in your event entity. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I'm not sure about the real expectation behind this but here is some tooltips: 1. Use the Inheritance mapping like @MigMolRod said and more specially https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance     2. Create 2 differents kind of Event entity and one attached to Cat the other attached to Dog.      3. Create an intermediate entities between Event and Cat, and Event and Dog that will make the relation between the Event and the target Animal. It's a mix between solution 1 and 2 xD

Comment: I am missing an understanding of the inheritance mapping feature of Doctrine, because this situation I am describing does not (as far as I can see) involve inheritance. Perhaps I will go for your 3rd option @Skuti

Comment: @GluePear to answer you, you could create a mapped superclass Event, with subclass CatEvent and DogEvent where CatEvent has a reference with Cat as $attribute and where DogEvent has a reference with Dog as $attribute.